# ng-maxlength $error message not showing

Tags: html, css, angularjs, validation

**Using** ng-maxlength="80" in `<input>` field.

**Expected this:**

```
<span class="select2-container text-error resize" ng-show="myForm.sampleName.$error.maxlength">This can't be longer than 80 characters.</span>
```

**to show** if `<input>` field has more than 80 characters.

However, error message does not show. **Input field just gets red border. Nothing else.**

Here is part of my form:

```
 <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-show = "isFormActive()" novalidate>
    <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label buffer-right"><h5>Name:</h5></label>

              <div class="input-prepend buffer-left">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
                <input type="text" name="sampleName" ng-model="person.name" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="80" placeholder="Enter your comments here" required /></br>
                <span class="select2-container text-error resize" ng-show="myForm.sampleName.$error.maxlength">
                  This can't be longer than 80 characters.</span>
              </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what is form `name` its confusing `form1` or `myForm`?

Comment: name of form is myForm. name of input field is "sampleName". Just changed it. Good catch!

Comment: Are you wrapping this in a form tag? if so- where?

Comment: then `myForm.name.$error.maxlength` should work in any case, does your field is inside `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Yes. It's wrapped inside a form tag. And no, not inside ng-repeat

Comment: Please show the entire code - including form tag.

Comment: added the necessary code

Comment: Appologies - novalidate is fine, I would check the css on the classes "select2-container text-error resize" you have on there, because this should work fine as is, maybe css is hiding it?

Comment: Would suggest posting this in a fiddle with your code then because the logic you have there is correct and should work.

Comment: Actually it is the class=" input-prepend" that's the problem. thanks